# Logout when token expired only when page is refreshed? Why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, access-token, bearer-token

i am finding difficult to understand if when token is expired and logout action is performed, this last action is only executed when the page is refreshed. Although when token expire the 401 code is thrown it still make the protected route visible and only with a refresh it logs out and goes to login.. Is it supposed to be like this or should not be happening and i am missing something?

Here's the code in front

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { logoutUser } from '../redux/ActionCreators';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl'

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        // send jwt to API to see if it's valid
        let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (token) {
            fetch(baseUrl + "protected", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ token })
            })
                .then((res) => {
                    return res.json()
                })
                .then((json) => {
                    if (json.success) {
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    dispatch(logoutUser())
                })
        } else {
            dispatch(logoutUser())
        }        
            
        }, [])
        
        
    return (<Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('token')
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/users/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />)
}
```

and the api called

```
protectedRouter.route('/')
    .options(cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) => { res.sendStatus(200) })
    .get(cors.cors, authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, async (req, res, next) => {
        res.statusCode = 403
        res.end('Operation not supported')
    })
    .post(cors.corsWithOptions,  async (req, res, next) => {
        const token = req.body.token
        
        if (token) {
         try {
          return jwt.verify(token, process.env.secretKey);
         } catch (err) {
          return null;
         }
        }
        return null;
})
```

Comment: not worked a lot with hooks, but when the first time it loads since you have a valid token and you are using promises, it would eventually fetch the 401 after this component is already rendered. I don't see it bound with redux store either, so how it will refresh? Does logout user action do anything to re-render the page?

Comment: hey there. thank for repling... the login phase is being made with redux, the protected route has all the code above and its all i was thinking to make it work and also by looking to examples to make this work. when the token expire it throws an error with verify token so a 401 status code is thrown and pages with protected route will show the error and not the content but the pages are still there and can navigate through them. Only when i refresh the page it logs out and the protected route are not visible or accessible anymore, so i am confused if it is necessary in a real application this.

Answer (score 0):

Can be various workaround, the easiest would be just re-render the component. just an example. Might not be the cleanest, but it will give you an idea

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { token, setToken } = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
        // send jwt to API to see if it's valid
        const token_from_storage = localStorage.getItem("token");
        setToken(token_from_storage);
        
        if (token_from_storage) {

        fetch(baseUrl + "protected", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ token })
        })
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json()
            })
            .then((json) => {
                if (json.success) {
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setToken(undefined);
                dispatch(logoutUser())
            })
    } else {
        setToken(undefined);
        dispatch(logoutUser())
    }
}, [])
            
    return (<Route {...rest} render={props => (
                token
                    ? <Component {...props} />
                    : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/users/login', state: { from:                       
             props.location } }} />
            )} />)
```

It will re-render the component when the token is invalidated or is not found from the storage. HTH.

Comment: i changed const { token, setToken } = useDispatch()  to  const [ token, setToken ] = useState(); as it was not a function and  it would not allow me to make the application work, but unfortunately it does not allow me to go to the protected route at all.. it does not allow me to go to the protected pages, i am logged in but when trying to go inside its like a refresh page over and over :/